# Python Web Crawler with stored Web History

Tags: google-chrome, web-crawler, browser-history, computer-forensics

I'm Creating a Python Web crawler, with the ability to browse web history & parse through the information and store important information within a Database for Forensics/Academic Purposes. I understand the functionality to browse web sites but the part I'm struggling with is to be able too crawl through web history I will give a scenario:

During Forensic Investigation.

You have been given a full Forensic Image of Suspects Computer, you then locate the AppData folder for Google Chrome which stores all information about suspect including form information, credentials & web history.

How would I set up the web crawler to only search through data in the suspects web history.

I am also having issues accessing the information stored within Google Chrome User Data to try view my personal information which is stored here as a start, I am currently attempting to use DB Browser to view the files to try see my own web history however I'm not having much luck with this. Any Suggestions

For those interested in this project of mine I can update this thread as I go so you can see the progress of my web-crawler the end result will have the ability to take web-history and data from public & private websites sort important information i.e. name, address, D.O.B into a database for to be used later as a biographic dictionary.

I WILL STRESS THIS AGAIN AS THIS IS ALL FOR ACADEMIC PURPOSES IN CONTROLLED ENVIROMENT AND USED ON A TEST/FAKE ACCOUNT

Answer (score 0):

Hindsight (https://github.com/obsidianforensics/hindsight) is an open source tool written in Python that can parse a ton of information from the files in /Google/Chrome/User Data/ directory.

You could look at it's source for inspiration, or just run the tool and parse its output (it can produce XLSX, JSON, or SQLite) in your crawler.

Comment: thanks anything is a help at this point i'm finding it difficult to get a start